# Convert existing field mapping to geoip

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have already parsed a log file using logstash and put it into elasticsearch. I have a field called IP and it is mapped as a string now. I want to convert the existing mapping in elasticsearch to geoip without running logstash again. I have few million records in elasticsearch with this field. I want to convert the mapping of IP from string to geoip in all the records.

Comment: Are we talking about a normal `logstash-*` index or is it a custom one for other needs?

Comment: Normal logstash index

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you still have to use Logstash for this because `geoip` is a Logstash filter and Elasticsearch doesn't have access to the GeoIP database by itself.

Fear not, though, you won't need to re-run Logstash on the raw log lines, you can simply re-index your ES documents using an [`elasticsearch` input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html) plugin and an [`elasticsearch` output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) plugin and by tacking the [`geoip` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-geoip.html) inbetween in order to transform the `IP` field into the `geoip` one.

Since you can't modify the mapping of your current `IP` field from `string` to `geo_point`, we need to make sure your index is ready to ingest GeoIP data. First check with the following command if your index already contains a `geoip` field in your mapping (which would have been created by Logstash using its predefined standard `logstash-*` template).

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/logstash-xyz/_mapping
```

If you see a `geoip` field in the output of the above command, then you're good to go. Otherwise, we first need to create the `geoip` field with the type `geo_point`:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/logstash-xyz/_mapping/your_type -d '{
  "your_type": {
    "properties": {
      "geoip": {
        "type": "object",
        "dynamic": true,
        "properties": {
          "ip": {
            "type": "ip",
            "doc_values": true
          },
          "location": {
            "type": "geo_point",
            "doc_values": true
          },
          "latitude": {
            "type": "float",
            "doc_values": true
          },
          "longitude": {
            "type": "float",
            "doc_values": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Now your mapping is ready to receive GeoIP data. So, next we create a Logstash configuration file called `geoip.conf` that looks like this:

```
input {
  elasticsearch {
   hosts => "localhost:9200"
   index => "logstash-xyz"
  }
}
filter {
 mutate {
  remove_field => [ "@version", "@timestamp" ]
 }
 geoip {
  source => "IP"         <--- the field containing the IP string
 }
}
output {
 elasticsearch {
   host => "localhost"
   port => 9200
   protocol => "http"
   manage_template => false
   index => "logstash-xyz"
   document_id => "%{id}"
   workers => 1
 }
}
```

And then after setting the correct values (host + index), you can run this with `bin/logstash -f geoip.conf`. After running this, your documents should contain a new field called `geoip` with the GeoIP information.

Going forth, I suggest you directly add the `geoip` filter to your normal logstash configuration.